# C - Segmentation fault : 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

Hi I have to do a simulation of disk for my university.

I got 2 file :

tttfs.h :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct _disk disk;
typedef struct _block block;

struct _block{
    uint8_t *unBlock;
};

struct _disk{
    int id;
    block *diskBlock;
};
```

tfs_create.c :

```
#include "tttfs.h"

uint8_t little[4];

int tttfs_create(int size, char *name);
void inttolitend(uint32_t x, uint8_t* lit_int);

int main(){
    tttfs_create(7, "disk.tfs");
}

int tttfs_create(int size, char *name){
    FILE *f = NULL;
    if ((f = fopen(name, "wb"))!=NULL)
    {
    disk *d = malloc(sizeof(disk));
    d->diskBlock = malloc(1024);
    d->id = 1;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<size; i++){
       printf("%d\n", i);
       d->diskBlock[i].unBlock = malloc(1024); //I got the segmentation fault here
    }
    inttolitend(size, little);
    for(i = 0; i<4; i++){
       d->diskBlock[0].unBlock[i] = little[i];
    }
    for(i = 0; i<size; i++){
       fwrite(&d->diskBlock[i],1024,1,f);
    }
    }
    else
        printf("Erreur\n\n");
    return 0;
}

void inttolitend(uint32_t x, uint8_t* lit_int){
   lit_int[3] = (uint8_t)x / (256*256*256);
   lit_int[2] = (uint8_t)(x % (256*256*256)) / (256*256);
   lit_int[1] = (uint8_t)((x % (256*256*256)) % (256*256)) / 256;
   lit_int[0] = (uint8_t)((x % (256*256*256)) % (256*256)) % 256;
}
```

I want to write in a file a number of block (here 7), so I do malloc on size of my disk struct and then I do a malloc on diskBlock to make a table d->diskBlock[0].unBlock = malloc(1024); but not for more. how could I do a block[size] with my struct ? (I'm not good in c)

Comment: 1. Alaways check the return value of `malloc()` against `NULL`. 2. Why this `d->diskBlock = malloc(1024);`? it should be `malloc(size * sizeof(block));`!

Comment: why `d->diskBlock = malloc(1024);`? Don't use magic numbers.

Comment: I want that uint8_t *unBlock = malloc(1024);

Comment: When you're doing `d->diskBlock = malloc(1024)` you allocate 1024 *bytes* not `1024` `block` structures. While it may not be the cause of your crash, it *is* a problem.

Comment: This `fwrite(&d->diskBlock[i],1024,1,f);` seems to be the problem, what are you trying with it?

Comment: I want to write each block on disk in the file f. Here I want to write 7 block (size).

Comment: Again you seem to mistake a byte size with the number of elements. In your `fwrite` call you write 1024 *bytes* And the structure is only 4 or 8 bytes (depending on if you're on a 32 or 64 bit architecture). And to make it worse, the structure contains a pointer, and you write the pointer to the file and not the memory it points to.

Comment: By the way, your `inttolitend` seems overloy complicated. The normal way to convert values between endiannesses is to use bitwise anding and shifting, not divisions and modulo.

Comment: I changed that I don't have a segmentation fault anymore. But if my fwrite is a problem how could I know if I have the good file ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I change to :
for(i = 0; i<size; i++){
    fwrite(&d->diskBlock[i],sizeof(block),1,f);
 }

Comment: @Jackie That still won't solve the problem of you writing a *pointer* to the file, and not the memory it points to. You either needs to write e.g. `d->diskBlock[i].unBlock` *or* simply change the structure to contain an array instead.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg like that ? `fwrite(&d->diskBlock[i].unBlock,sizeof(uint8_t)*1024,1,f);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change this line

```
d->diskBlock = malloc(1024);
```

to

```
d->diskBlock = malloc(sizeof(block) * size);
```

---

And, this

```
d->diskBlock[i].unBlock = malloc(1024);
```

to

```
d->diskBlock[i].unBlock = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * 4);
```

Comment: But I don't thikn this is triggering `SIGSEGV`. 1024 is enough space, more than enough. It would need maximum `7 * sizeof(block)` or `56B` approximately assuming 64 bit pointers.

Comment: And how could I have a malloc(1024) on my block ? I need block[1024] length to simulate a disk.